# match fundction with data frames that are differently constructed

Tags: r

I am relatively new to R and I have hit a wall with trying to figure out how to do what I want to do. I went through many questions on StackOF but still could not figure it out (exactly). Here is what I am trying to do:

data frame 1:

```
d1 =c("2005/01/02")
d2 = c("2005/01/08") 
rm = c(13)
df1 = data.frame(d1, d2, rm)
```

data frame 2:

```
df2 <- as.data.frame(seq(as.Date("2005-01-02"), as.Date("2005-01-08"), by="days"))
colnames(df2)<-c("dtime")
```

What I hope to create:

```
df2$new <- if (df2$dtime >= df1$d1 AND <= df1$d2),
```

return `df1$rm` with the hopes of creating a variable `df2$new` looking like this in the end:

```
df2$new <- 13
View(df2)
```

I am essentially trying to match the value that corresponds to the week (`df1$rm`) to the individual days (`df2$new`) within that week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you might be looking for is sapply

```
df2$new <- sapply(df2$dtime, function(row){df1[((row >= as.Date(df1$d1)) + (row <= as.Date(df1$d2))) == 2,]$rm})
```

In R vectors being preferred to for loops. What I'm doing is taking df2's dtime column, and applying the function(row) to each in turn. This get's me a list of lookups into df1, will there always be an entry in df1 or do we need a default case?

Comment: It returns: ("undefined columns selected"). df1 has 526 observations(weeks) and there is an entry in each case for all three variables in df1.

Comment: I have just corrected it to use + rather than &&, try my updated version. Also I forgot the comma before the close square brackets doh.

Comment: Worked Beautifully, Thank you So much!

Comment: No problem, if you could hit the green tick to mark the answer as correct for other's future reference that would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If the dataframe is not too big, this would be really easy using a simple for loop:

```
d1 =c("2005/01/02")
d2 = c("2005/01/08") 
rm = c(13)
df1 = data.frame(d1, d2, rm)

df2 <- as.data.frame(seq(as.Date("2005-01-02"), as.Date("2005-01-08"), by="days"))
colnames(df2)<-c("dtime")

df2$new <- NA
for(i in 1:nrow(df1)) df2$new[df2$dtime >= as.Date(df1$d1[i]) & df2$dtime <= as.Date(df1$d2[i])] <- df1$rm[i]
```

Comment: Thank you Sam. It is a large data set around 520 weeks. It is google search data that is in weekly format. I already changed the dates in the data frames to display the start of the week in column 1 and the end of the week in column 2, with the value that corresponds to that week in coumn 3.

Comment: So are you saying a for loop won't work?  I think this code produces the output you described and can work with data that has several rows in `df1`.  If this doesn't work, can you explain what specifically doesn't work about it?

Comment: Thank you Sam. It is a large data set around 520 weeks.  I already changed the dates in the data frames to display the start of the week in column 1 and the end of the week in column 2, with the value that corresponds to that week in column 3. I am trying to get the weekly data into daily data by matching each day in the week with the value it had according to the weekly index. I tried your approach but it did not provide me with the correct value; I obtained a much larger value for each entry (61 where it should be 13) it is exactly 48 more for each entry/value it should return?

Comment: I edited the solution to include the code that creates `df1` and `df2`.  What happens when you paste the code in directly?  I think there's a possibility that the data you are working with is different than what is posted here?

Comment: I used it directly, just changing the names. I created the data frames for explanatory purposes for Stack Overflow but it is already in data frame form in my data set: rightmove$d1 = start of week date variable in weeks from 2005-01-02 to 2015-01-25 ; rightmove$d2 = end of week date variable in weeks starting at 2005-01-08 to 2015-01-31 and rightmove$rmsv is the value that is associated with a specific week. It has 526 observations for each. Then I have a dataframe "dayvec" with variable dayvec$dtime for each day (3682 days) and want to MATCH each day with the weekly value?

Comment: so the code i copied directly is: dayvec$new <- NA
for(i in 1:nrow(rightmove)) dayvec$new[dayvec$dtime >= as.Date(rightmove$d1[i]) & dayvec$dtime <= as.Date(rightmove$d2[i])] <- rightmove$rmsv[i]